# jsonEncode generating error while converting object to jsonstring in flutter

Tags: flutter

For explaining what I am facing problem while creating a jsonstring from object list,I have created this basic demo,
actually I am trying to create a backup file for saving records but I am getting an error while jsonEncode.

getting following error

```
Converting object to an encodable object failed: Instance of 'TransactionModel'
```

```
class TransactionModel {
  String id;
  bool isexpense;
  DateTime date;
  double amount;

  TransactionModel({
    this.amount = 0.00,
    required this.id,
    this.isexpense = true,
    required this.date,
  });

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    return {
      'id': id,
      'isexpense': isexpense,
      'date': date,
      'amount': amount,
    };
  }
}
```

```
void main() {

  List<TransactionModel> trans = [
    TransactionModel(
      date: DateTime.now(),
        id: '1',),
  ];

  String result = jsonEncode(trans);//error bcz of jsonEncode

  print(result);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't encode an `object` with custom property like `DateTime`, you need first convert it to `map`, then encode it, try this:

```
void main() {

  List<TransactionModel> trans = [
    TransactionModel(
      date: DateTime.now(),
        id: '1',),
  ];

  var listOfMap = trans.map((e) => e.toJson()).toList();

  String result = jsonEncode(listOfMap);

  print(result);
}
```

Comment: But I have already tried this

Comment: import 'dart:convert';

main() {
  User user = User('bezkoder', 21);

  String jsonUser = jsonEncode(user);
  print(jsonUser);
}

Comment: its working.. and can be directly convert object to string json

Comment: https://www.bezkoder.com/dart-flutter-convert-object-to-json-string/

Comment: I updated my answer, The example that you provide only works when you define TransactionModel with string or int or variable like that, not works with dateTime, if you want to use this kind of variable you need to convert it the way I answerd. @IrfanGanatra

Comment: The approach in that page won't works on dynamic classes as property, its only works when you use static type like string, int,... . @IrfanGanatra

Comment: Yes..I got your point and checked with editing date:date.toString() in  my code and it worked....So converting to map is compulsory while using such datetime..

Comment: it took my 2 days for backup data..one problem solved and another arrived...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75396592/os-error-permission-denied-errno-13-while-creating-backup-file-in-flutter

Comment: eamirho3ein can u check my question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75446794/unexpected-output-while-using-get-put-in-flutter