# OS Error: Permission denied, errno = 13 while creating backup file in flutter

Tags: flutter

I have gone through all StackOverflow questions regarding the same error..and almost applied all but can't solve this error...

I am trying on my physical device...dont know what's wrong with my code

error is

```
ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: FileSystemException: Creation failed, path = '/storage/emulated/0//Passman/' (OS Error: Permission denied, errno = 13)
```

manifest file

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.untitled16">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

   <application
       android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
        android:label="untitled16"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
```

and here is my basic coding

```
Future<Directory> _getDirectory() async {
  const String pathExt = '/Passman/';
  Directory newDirectory = Directory('/storage/emulated/0/' + pathExt);
  if (await newDirectory.exists() == false) {
    return newDirectory.create(recursive: true);
  }
  return newDirectory;
}

void main() async {

  List<TransactionModel> trans = [
    TransactionModel(
      date: DateTime.now(),
      id: '1',),
  ];

  String result = jsonEncode(trans);
  Directory dir = await _getDirectory();
  String formattedDate = DateTime.now()
      .toString()
      .replaceAll('.', '-')
      .replaceAll(' ', '-')
      .replaceAll(':', '-');
  String path = '${dir.path}$formattedDate.json';
  File backupFile = File(path);
  await backupFile.writeAsString(result);
  print(result);
}
```

Comment: what do you see if you print `Directory('/storage/emulated/0').statSync().modeString()`?

Comment: its showing rwxrwx---

Comment: and If I remove my pathExt variable it showing new error 'ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path = '/storage/emulated/0/2023-02-09-16-37-53-553373.json' (OS Error: Operation not permitted, errno = 1)'

Comment: this is because you are "others" and do not have any permissions in that folder (`---`), for more check https://jfrog.com/community/devops/linux-permissions-dos-and-donts/#:~:text=What%20are%20Linux%20File%20Permissions,access%20specific%20files%20and%20directories.

Comment: I m really tired by solving this..so I changed my coding to this...String result = jsonEncode(transactionmaplist);
    File backupFile = File('${Directory.systemTemp.path}/logic.json');

    await backupFile.writeAsString(result);

Comment: No error but where can I find this logic.json file...

Comment: cannot you use this https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-io/Directory/current.html as a base folder?

Comment: thanks for ur help..but it looks need to study more over this..my aim was simple to create a backup file  of object list ,in device..but its taking my too much time...